# overide reindex searchkick method error :NoMethodError (super: no superclass method `reindex' for #<Searchkick::RecordIndexer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, searchkick

We are trying to overide the reindex method of Searchkick in order to avoid reindexing in case we are on local env.

So we created a initializers/record_indexer.rb :

```
class Searchkick::RecordIndexer
  def reindex(options= {})
    unless Rails.env == 'local'
      super(options)
    end
  end
end
```

When I try to update an associated model that cause a reindexation of my 'indexed record' it throws a NoMethodError (super: no superclass method `reindex' for #<Searchkick::RecordIndexer)

I notice that searchkick has at least 3 reindex methods in:

- Searchkick::RecordIndexer (for Foo.first.reindex I guess)
- Searchkick::Index (for Foo.reindex I guess)
- Searchkick::Model (for ??)

Did someone already have this kind of problematic on the #reindex method of Gem Searckick (v4.4.2)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you are completely replacing a method with your implementation.

If you override a method, and want to call the original, you have two options:

1. Store the original method with an alias

   ```
   class Searchkick::RecordIndexer
     alias_method :orig_reindex, :reindex

     def reindex(options={})
       unless Rails.env == 'local'
         orig_reindex(options)
       end
     end
   end
   ```
2. Prepend a module

   ```
   module YourPatch
     def reindex(options={})
       unless Rails.env == 'local'
         super # no need to specify args if it's just pass-through
       end
     end
   end

   Searchkick::RecordIndexer.prepend(YourPatch)
   ```

Comment: First options suits my needs better since the gem Searchkick automatically use .reindex on models indexed. Because I never use the Searchkick::RecordIndexer class myself I prefer to override it. Didn't know about #alias_method but it looks I should !